# python cursor FROM %s

Tags: python, cursor

I try to execute this request :

```
cur.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM %s WHERE equipement_id = %s", (table,eq_id))
```

But i have error because the FROM %s is not build correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
cur.execute("""SELECT MAX(id) FROM %s WHERE equipement_id = %s""" % (table, eq_id))
```

Comment: Did you hear about SQL-injections?

Comment: I check before insert and it's not for website but for micro-controller. Thanks for solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to do it in 2 steps:

```
table_name = 'stuff'
query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM {0} WHERE equipement_id = %s".format(table_name)
cur.execute(query, eq_id)
```

Why? - Database connectors tend to only allow you to substitute values into the query, not arbitrary pieces like table names or expressions. For example, [from psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

> Only variable values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to set table or field names. For these elements, ordinary string formatting should be used before running execute().

And obviously:

### triple-check if the value of `table_name` isn't user controlled and is really a valid table name!

Please read [the problem with the query parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) section in psycopg2 docs (even if you end up using another database; the remarks there are quite general).